# GSM Module USB port Changing

Tags: gsm, openwrt, 4g, quectel

On OpenWRT devices, we use QUECTEL EC25-E GSM Module, internet is disconnecting, when it disconnect we send AT+CFUN=1,1 to GSM Modem.
Before send command devices are;

```
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   0 Jun 27 15:35 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   1 Jun 27 15:35 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   2 Jun 27 15:35 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   3 Jun 27 15:35 /dev/ttyUSB3
```

After I send command

```
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   0 Jun 27 15:39 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   2 Jun 27 17:46 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   3 Jun 27 15:39 /dev/ttyUSB3
crw-------    1 root     root      188,   4 Jun 27 15:39 /dev/ttyUSB4
```

devices are changing, it results internet cannot be connected.

Is there a way to prevent?

Comment: Did you tried using udev rule to link specific usb device(vendor id, product id) to specific  symlink? For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356358/6273349

Comment: @FSA is this still an issue for you? Have you investigated whether using a different `ttyUSB*` interface gets things working again?

Comment: I solved issue, If I send command bind, unbind it solves it. Thanks.